# VB Script add and delete worksheet to a specific excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to add a worksheet to a specific excel and further delete the same sheet after some operations. I am using the below code but this creates a new excel rather than adding workbook to the specific excel i want. Is there any way i can achieve this?

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject(“Excel.Application”)
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set colSheets = objWorkbook.Sheets
colSheets.Add ,,9
```

Comment: What is the name of the workbook you would like to add the sheet to?

Comment: Anything random probably book1.xlsx

Comment: An existing workbook? Or do you need to add the new workbook too?

Comment: Existing work book.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject(“Excel.Application”)
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.Sheets.Add ,,9
```

This will add 9 worksheets to the workbook you create during the procedure.